# Copy file from commandline, paste into Gnome window or vice-versa

Tags: copy-paste

There are plenty of examples how to copy the "contents" of a file from command line with the help of `xclip` or `xsel`. What I am looking for is to copy a file from the command line and paste into the file explorer. So I will use a command to copy a file, not only the contents, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste it in UI.

**updated**
`xclip-copyfile` and `xclip-pastefile` work close to what I expect, but when I run `xclip-copyfil`e, I can only paste with `xclip-pastefile` command, not GUI paste.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually mean when you refer to "contents" and "file". Eg, `xsel` and `xclip` do not copy the contents of a file. From `man xsel`  *"DESCRIPTION: Retrieve and set the X selection"*... Do you mean that you want to copy a ***filename*** to the clipboard and then use Ctrl-v in the File Browser's GUI to actually copy that ***file*** (ie. the *filename* and the *file's contents*) into the browser's current directory?

Comment: yes Peter. i meant what you mean. i am not sure when the file is actually "opened" when you do GUI copy/paste. But most likely, only file ref is copied into clip, when you paste then source file is opened and copied to target. Xsel xclip examples i found, opens file and copies content and expects you to paste content into a file editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Nautilus, in Ubuntu, as my File Browser, so I can't speak for  any other browser.
The way in which Nautilus handles pasting a file via `Ctrl-v` is quite local to Nautilus, ie. Nautilus only recognizes Ctrl-v as *paste a file* in response to a *copy file* command which was issued while in *nautilus* itself.  This means that you can't use Ctrl-v to paste a file whose path you copied in another application.

However, if it suits you, Ctrl+Shift+v can be bound to a script which runs under `nautilus-scripts-manager`. With this script, you can do pretty much whatever you like.

`nautilus-scripts-manager` gives you access to some fundamental information about the current directory and which files/directories are selected.  One thing I particularly like about "nautilus-scripts" is that it adds its scripts to the `File` menu item (as well as to the context-menu). This allows you to set a key-binding which is local to [Nautilus 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3) or [Nautilus 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5241/ubuntu-editable-menu-accelerators-on-a-per-app-basis-where-is-this-option).

Here is a rough example, using your already mentioned `xclip-pastefiles` example. Note, that as it stands now, it requires that you set up the `xclip-copyfiles` before running this Ctrl-Shift-v *paste* script.
Once you have run the setup `xclip-copyfiles`, you need only navigate to a Nautilus window, and selcet the  target directory (or a file in that directory) and press your script's keybinding: *Ctrl-Shift-v*

```
#!/bin/bash   
# Note: `leafpad' is a simple text editor which doubles as a quick-and-easy testing messsage-box

dir=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" |sed -n 1p)
if [[ -n "$dir" ]] ;then
    # target dir from `Nautilus Scripts' (1st priority)    
    if [[ -e "$dir" ]] ;then
       [[ -d "$dir" ]] || dir="${dir%/*}" 
       [[ -d "$dir" ]] || dir=
    fi
else
  # target dir from $1 (2nd priority)
    dir="$1"
    if [[ -e "$dir" ]] ;then
       [[ -d "$dir" ]] || dir="${dir%/*}" 
       [[ -d "$dir" ]] || dir=
    fi
fi

if [[ -z "$dir" ]] ;then
    # target dir from clipboard (if not in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT.. or  $1)
   dir="$(xclip -o -sel c)"
   if [[ -e "$dir" ]] ;then
      [[ -d "$dir" ]] || dir="${dir%/*}" 
      [[ -d "$dir" ]] || dir= 
   else
      dir=
   fi
fi

[[ -d "$dir" ]] || { echo "$(basename "$0"): target directory not found in clipboard" |leafpad; exit 1; } 

{ cd   "$dir"
  echo "Current  Directory:" 
  echo "  $dir"
  echo "======="
  echo  xclip-pastefile # run your command  (`echo' is for testing)
} 2>&1 |leafpad
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. worked like a charm. a couple of notes for other readers. there is nautilus-scripts-manager and there is also nautilus-script-manager. I think second one is commandline version. The scripts are executed in active windows folder,  created this file "/usr/share/nautilus-scripts/paste.sh"